# How to send Touch command from APK?

Tags: android

I want to develop a ANDROID application for UI testing. which send 
ADB command or some other method to send touch even. I tried using Runtime.getRuntime().exec
function but it is not working.

I don't want to use any interface from PC, just an APK which save and play event with in device.

Please suggest me any feasible  solution.

Comment: By design, you cannot do this on a secured (which is to say typical) device without either using a pc, using a pc or other adb usb host (even another phone!) to switch adb to tcp mode, or breaking the security model using some exploit.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `monkey` do it:
InputManager.getInstance().injectInputEvent(keyEvent,
         InputManager.INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_WAIT_FOR_RESULT)

You may check out the code and have a look.
Browser the code online at [androidxref](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/development/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey/MonkeyKeyEvent.java#100).
Be aware that, some permission is needed to do this: android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS.
To get this permission, your app must has be signed with the same key as the platform.

Comment: I don't want to use any interface from PC, just an APK which save and play event with in device.

Comment: Well, monkey/monkeyrunner both depends on the API of android. So, for your app, just use these APIs directly. No interface from PC at all.